# RemoveComments in html-minifier by command line

Tags: html, npm, minify

I want to use `html-minifier` to minify my html files.

I have install it by `npm install -g html-minifier`

However, `sudo html-minifier rb.html --removeComments` did NOT remove the comments in `rb.html`.

Does anyone know how to use it?

Additionally, I just want to minify the size of the html files by keeping exactly the same layout, what are conventional parameters that we put to `html-minifier`?

Answer (score 8):

You can target all html files in a specified directory with the following command:

```
html-minifier --input-dir dist --output-dir dist
```

With this example script I am compressing all html files in **dist** and outputting them to the same directory — essentially replacing the uncompressed html files with the compressed ones.

The command above actually doesn't do anything to the files because no options were defined. Some useful options are:

- `--collapse-whitespace`: Collapse whitespace that contributes to text nodes in a document tree.
- `--remove-comments`: Remove HTML comments
- `--minify-css`: Minifies embedded and inline CSS (`<style></style>` and `style=""`)
- `--minify-js`: Minifies embedded and inline JS (`<script></script>` and e.g `onload=""`)

Here's a command that you may end up with:

```
html-minifier --input-dir dist --output-dir dist --remove-comments --collapse-whitespace --minify-js --minify-css
```

To see the complete list of available options, run `html-minifier -h`.